# Font Awesome Displaying Empty Boxes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, bootstrap-4

It was displaying the Font Awesome properly, but now it won't, though nothing has changed. I've tried many solutions and nothing seems to work. I'm trying to display it as a placeholder.

**Here is my code (HTML / CSS):**

```css
input {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
```

```html
<!-- included -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<input id="user" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username&#xf007;"/>
```

Does anyone know the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use your inspector. Any 404s?  Cross origin blocks?  Is everything coming in 200?

Comment: @RobertWade there's no errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The empty box is shown because the character (`&#xf007;`) is not available on the font family of Bootstrap. To solve this issue you have to overwrite the the font-family of Bootstrap. So you can use `!important` on the `font-family` rule or be more specific on the CSS rule itself by using a class for example:

```css
input {
  font-family: sans-serif, 'FontAwesome'!important;
}
input.more-specific {
  font-family: sans-serif, 'FontAwesome';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- the input elements -->
<input id="user" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username &#xf007;"/>
<input id="user" type="text" class="form-control more-specific" placeholder="username &#xf007;"/>
```

You can also set the CSS class `.fa` to the `<input>` like the following so you don't need to add additionaly CSS to the `<input>`:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- input element -->
<input id="user" type="text" class="form-control fa" placeholder="username &#xf007;"/>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Just what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following line that you have added in your HTML file should load the FontAwesome. You have got that right. Super. :)

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Now to fix the font awesome issue change the markup of the input box to :

```
<div class="input-group mb-2 mb-sm-0">
  <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Username">
 </div>
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Sea asked for usage as a placeholder, not as a input-group-addon.

Comment: This helped me. I had a missing "fa" class.